# Cannot initialise Vuex store from localStorage for my Auth in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js and I'm trying to make my own authentication. It works fine but when I refresh the page the state is go back to initial data so I tried to initialise Vuex store from localStorage like this:

`export const state = () => ({
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    loggedInUser: localStorage.getItem('user') || '',
})`
but it give me this error `localStorage is not defined` but `localStorage.setItem` works fine in actions

This is the full code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const state = () => ({
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    loggedInUser: localStorage.getItem('user') || '',
})

export const getters = {
    status (state) {
        return state.status
    },
    authenticated (state) {
        return !!state.token
    },
    token (state) {
        return state.token
    },
    loggedInUser (state) {
        return state.loggedInUser
    },
}

export const mutations = {
    auth_request(state) {
        state.status = 'loading'
    },
    auth_success(state, token) {
        state.status = 'success'
        state.token = token
    },
    auth_error(state) {
        state.status = 'error'
    },
    logout(state) {
        state.status = ''
        state.token = ''
        state.loggedInUser = {}
    },
    auth_success2 (state, loggedInUser) {
        state.loggedInUser = Object.assign({}, loggedInUser)
    }
}

export const actions = {

    login({commit}, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            commit('auth_request')
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', data)
                .then((res) => {
                    const loggedInUser = Object.assign({}, res.data.data)
                    const token = res.data.meta.token
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
                    localStorage.setItem('user', loggedInUser.name)
                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ token
                    commit('auth_success', token)
                    commit('auth_success2', loggedInUser)
                    this.$router.push('/')
                    resolve(res)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    commit('auth_error')
                    console.log(error)
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include where this error is being thrown, but I'm going to assume it's in your server logs.

What's happening is Nuxt is initializing itself **server side**, begins to set up the store, and hits the localStorage declaration.  The server does not have localstorage, so this will fail.

To get around this, I'd suggest using a plugin, with the .client suffix, and fetch the values from localStorage during the client side initialization:

```
// the .client suffix is required here to tell nuxt to only run this client side.
// ~/plugins/vuex-init.client.js
export default ({ store }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || ''
  const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('user') || ''

  store.commit('setToken', token)
  store.commit('setUser', user)
}
```

If you don't want to do the work yourself, I've used [this](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) before and have had great results with it.

Comment: Ty so much I really appreciate your help