# Nuxt load data from localstorage into vuex on startup

Tags: nuxt.js, local-storage, vuex

I have the following problem in Nuxt. I want to load account data from localstorage to Vuex store on initial page load. I first tried to do this in the default layout. However, it seems like the child components are rendered first, and then the layout.

So I rewrote it as a plugin and as middleware. The code looks like this "plugins/account-loader.js":

```
export default ({ store }) => {
    if (process.client) {
        try {

            let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
            store.commit("auth/setUser", user);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/account-loader', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

The problem has already been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277093/cannot-initialise-vuex-store-from-localstorage-for-my-auth-in-nuxt). However, the answer described there does not work for me. The same error message appears here.

Would be happy if you can help. I think I have not yet understood something basic about Nuxt (it is an existing vue SPA app migrated to Nuxt).

Comment: if your using ssr, then you can use nuxtServerInit to populate user store from the server, which is always better then using localstrage to store creds etc

Comment: Thank you it is working. For me it was new that the vuex store is also available on the server side.